# Java app handling being in different language OS

Tags: java, windows, path

I'm finishing a App which I intend to test on my friends' PCs.

However some of them don't have Windows in English, mine is and the code reflects so.
The final app will require parsing a .txt file which is created in the same folder as the apps .exe.

How can I guarantee in my code that when parsing it will look at the correct folder?
Currently I tell him the complete path where the .txt is, but as I said my OS is in English and my friends' might not be.

Or this it not matter as long as I write the paths in English?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `C:\Program Files` versus `C:\Programme` and so on. Check whether you can use `System.getProperty("user.dir");`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the paths are the same, the language of the OS doesn't matter, at least not for finding the correct folder. So the paths don't even need to be in English... as long as they are the same.

Ofcourse when you have paths that are dependent on the OS language, you won't be able to use this method of using the path...